# Reactive Forms value is null

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular-reactive-forms

I am building a student system with spring boot and angular. When I want to update the contact information,I want the informtaion from the backend to be written to the necessary placesint he automatic form. My code part is like below bot it doennot write any value, although the backend part is full of data.

---

```
@GetMapping("/Person/{personId}")
public Person getPersonID(@PathVariable(value = "personId") Integer personId) {
  Person person = editorService.findBypersonId(personId);
  return person;
}
```

---

```
data: Person = new Person();

ngOnInit() {
  this.reloadData();
  this.reloadForm();
}
    
reloadData() {
  this.personService.getPErsonId(this.personId).subscribe(response => {
    this.data = response;
  });
}

reloadForm() {
  this.ilanOlusturForm = new FormGroup({
    personName: new FormControl(
      this.data ? this.data.personName : "", [Validators.required]
    ),
  });
}

export class Person{
  name:string;
  surname:string;
  ....
}


<nb-card>
    <nb-card-body>
        <nb-stepper #stepper>
            <nb-step [stepControl]="ilanOlusturForm" >

                <form [formGroup]="ilanOlusturForm" class="step-container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="label">Personel</label>
                                <input type="text" nbInput fullWidth fieldSize="small"
                                    formControlName="personName">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </nb-step>
        </nb-stepper>
    </nb-card-body>
</nb-card>
```

---

```
  ngOnInit() {
  this.reloadData();
  
}

reloadData() {
  this.personService.getPErsonId(this.personId).subscribe(response => {
    this.data = response;
    
    // Move this line to here
    this.reloadForm();
    
  });
}

reloadForm() {
  this.ilanOlusturForm = new FormGroup({
    personName: new FormControl(this.data ? this.data.personName : "", [Validators.required]),
  });
}
```

[image]

Comment: Let `this.reloadForm();` this call inside you subscribe statement of `reloadData`. Since `reloadData` is a async operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move `this.reloadForm();` to inside `reloadData()`.

```js
data: Person = new Person();

ngOnInit() {
  this.reloadData();
  
}

reloadData() {
  this.personService.getPErsonId(this.personId).subscribe(response => {
    this.data = response;
    
    // Move this line to here
    this.reloadForm();
    
  });
}

reloadForm() {
  this.ilanOlusturForm = new FormGroup({
    personName: new FormControl(this.data ? this.data.personName : "", [Validators.required]),
  });
}


export class Person {


  name: string;
  surname: string;
  ....

}
```

Comment: Hello thank for your reply first  of all but I got an error. Error ss I am attaching to the question.

Comment: @zdnmn I see, maybe you miss [formGroup]="ilanOlusturForm" in HTML, could you check that? If it already exists, please attach your HTML to the question too.